# Delphi: How to move a class out of a unit;avoid circular references

Tags: delphi, refactoring, circular-dependency, delphi-5, circular-reference

> **Question:** i want to split two classes out to their own file, while avoiding circular references.

i have a unit with some classes (and some enumerations and constants). Anyone will recognize [Click and Clack the tappet brothers](http://cartalk.com):

```
unit Cartalk;

interface

type
   TSolution = (solTransmission, solBrakes, solGremlins);

   TTappetBrother = class(TObject)
   public
      function GetSolution: TSolution; virtual; abstract;
   end;

   TClick = class(TTappetBrother)
   public      
      function GetSolution: TSolution; override;
   end;

   TClack = class(TTapperBrother)
   public
      function GetSolution: TSolution; override;
   end;

implementation

function TClick.GetSolution: TSolution;
begin
   Result := solTransmission;
end;

function TClack.GetSoltution: TSolution;
begin
   Result := solGremlins;
end;

end.
```

Now obviously my two classes `TClick` and `TClick` are quite complex. For manageability i'd like to split `TClick` and `TClack` out to their own units ***while not breaking any existing external code***.

My first crack at it would be:

```
unit Cartalk;

interface

uses
   Cartalk_Click, Cartalk_Clack;

type
   TSolution = (solTransmission, solBrakes, solGremlins);

   TTappetBrother = class(TObject)
   public
      function GetSolution: TSolution; virtual; abstract;
   end;

   TClick = Cartalk_Click.TClick; //alias brought in from Cartalk_Click.pas

   TClack = Cartalk_Clack.TClack; //alias brought in from Cartalk_Clack.pas

 implementation

 end.
```

Perfect, i have all the same classes available in `Cartalk.pas`, now i just have to write `Cartalk_Click.pas` and `Cartalk_Clack.pas`:

```
unit Cartalk_Click;

interface

type
   TClick = class(TTappetBrother)
   public      
      function GetSolution: TSolution; override;
   end;

implementation

function TClick.GetSolution: TSolution;
begin
   Result := solTransmission;
end;

end.
```

Problem, of course, is that `TTappetBrother` and `TSolution` are not declared in this unit. So we add a reference to where they live to the `uses`, watch it fail, and reach the heart of my question:

```
unit Cartalk_Click;

interface

uses
   Cartalk;

type
   TClick = class(TTappetBrother)
   public      
      function GetSolution: TSolution; override;
   end;

implementation

function TClick.GetSolution: TSolution;
begin
   Result := solTransmission;
end;

end.
```

There is now a circular reference between `Cartalk` and `Cartalk_Click`.

**Note:** Of course i don't have a Cartalk unit, with Click and Clack the tapper brothers - this is just an example. In reality i have 3 classes, 20 enumerations, and 293 constants in my unit.

Comment: "Tappet" (eg "tap it") Brothers.  Just sayin'

Comment: **Edit**: Fixed one typo of tappet.

Comment: Adding a unit to the `uses` clause in every unit in a few projects is too difficult?

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: Yes.  If you can't accept my question as valid: a terrorist has taken my wife hostage, and will kill her if i cannot split `TClick` and `TClack` to a separate unit without breaking existing code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a unit:

```
unit Tappet;

interface

type
   TSolution = (solTransmission, solBrakes, solGremlins);

   TTappetBrother = class(TObject)
   public
      function GetSolution: TSolution; virtual; abstract;
   end;

implementation

end.
```

and use it in the `Click` and the `Clack` units. Then write the `CarTalk` unit to use all three and export the needed types in its interface. No circular references needed.

Comment: This is the solution, I think. By "export the needed types", I assume you mean like `TClick = class(Click.TClick);` ?

Comment: More or less. You don't need the `class` keyword. It is just aliasing as done in the question.

Comment: @Ian Boyd: Like the VCL does. For instance, `TPoint` is defined in `Types.pas` (which you seldom see in your `uses` clause), but in `Windows.pas` (which is almost always in this clause), you "export" it: `type TPoint = Types.TPoint;` (And, yes, `const` works like `type` in this respect.)